# Seeking good file-upload app for Django admin site

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-admin

Im seeking file uploader for general purposes. It means that admin-backend user should be able to upload some files, preferably from any place in admin-site, and use links to this files in other apps.

Such idea might came to somebody else head too, very likely, and library with implementation of it can exist. 
Can somebody give any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django Filebrowser 
Link Below :-

https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-filebrowser/